# Unable to update parent prop in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I can insert the input value say "1,2,3" and when backspace it removes all but in the console "1" is still shown i.e., `House{props{house{property{rent:1}}}}`

I am providing the code here which has 3 files.

`(1) house.js`

```
import ValInput from "main/components/val-input";

class House extends Component {
  state = {
    rent:"",
  };

componentDidMount() {

    if (this.props.house.rent) {
      const { rent} = this.props.house;
      this.setState({ rent });
    }
  }

onChange = (e) => {
    const rent = parseInt(e.target.value.replace(string);

    this.setState({
      rent,
    });
  };

render(){
const {house} = this.props;
const {rent} = this.state;
...
<ValInput
 type="text"
  value={ rent }
      onChange={e => {
          this.onChange(e);
       }}
   />
}
```

`(2) val-input\index.js`

```
    import React from "react";
    import Input from "main/components/input";

    const ValInput = props => (
      <Input
        {...props}
        type={props.type ? props.type : "text"}
      />
    );

    export default valInput;
```

`(3) components/input/index.js`

```
import React from "react";

const noOp = () => {};

const Input = ({
  onBlur = xP,
  ...otherProps
}) => (
  <input
    onBlur={e => {
      e.target.placeholder = placeholder;
      onBlur(e);
    }}
    {...otherProps}
  />
);

export default Input;
```

The expected result should be, after emptying the value say with backspace, and visit the page next time, the input field should be empty and should not show old value.

Comment: Please check `onChange` it seems to be incorrect (or may be you forget some code?)

Comment: Thanks, it is correct...I didn't add regular expression...but showing limited code..

Comment: can you add a plunker or fiddle for the same

Comment: You don't seem to be using <ValInput /> anywhere.

tbh there isn't enough correct information unique to the project in order to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, the ValInput is used for entering value inside the input field, thanks before i kept it as<input/> now edited back to <ValInput/>, rest of it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For updating @NaderZouaoui, has given me an example how to do Call back :
1. Child file :
onChange={e => {
          this.onChange(e);
        }}
onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      rent
    });
    this.props.callback(rent);
  };
2. Parent file :
 state = {
    rent: ""
  };
  handleChangeRent = newRent => {
    this.setState({ rent: newRent });
  };
render(){
return(
<House house={{ rent }} callback={this.handleChangeRent} />
      );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this CodeSandbox out I replicated your code and if I understood the problem right then fixed it 
https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html

Comment: Wow, your original Idea and help through CodeSandbox has helped alot, actually the work you have sent me for doing Callback has indeed worked, but as per my work I need to do make changes in the Query and update it in Cache..! But yours Call back was excellent. Thanks alot !